# Can't migrate db rails, getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dbmigrate

I am getting an error while migrating a database. The error is:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column roles.deleted_at does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"  WHERE ("roles"."deleted_at" I...
                                              ^
: SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"  WHERE ("roles"."deleted_at" IS NULL)
```

Here is my  part of schema.rb:

```
create_table "roles", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "title"
t.integer  "resource_id"
t.string   "resource_type"
t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
t.datetime "deleted_at"
end
```

I tried to make:

```
rails generate migration AddDeletedAtToRoles deleted_at
```

But it did not help.

Comment: Are you using acts_as_paranoid gem? Also can you add here command you use for running migration and also your migrations files.

Comment: "Part of your schema.rb"... Can you show us the *migration* where this is created? It's possible your schema is out of sync with them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes what I do in order to get rid of these inconsistent database states is, if it's a simple fix, go into the actual database and fix manually whatever seems to be the problem in order to get migrations going again.

In your case it seems like you are missing the `deleted_at` column in the roles table. So what you could do is create the column yourself. In order to do that in Postgres you would need to do something like:

1. `psql your_database_name`
   once you are in there Alter your `roles` table and add the column you are missing using the following command.
2. `ALTER TABLE roles ADD COLUMN deleted_at date;`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If a column exists in your schema but a migration is failing because it's not found, you may be in an inconsistent database state (i.e. your database's current schema is not in line with schema.rb, nor can you migrate as the migrations are incompatible with your current state). There are lots of ways to get into that state, but in any case, your best bet is to wipe your database clean and migrate again:

```
bin/rake db:reset db:migrate
```

If that doesn't work, you have more serious issues. If this is a fairly new app, `bin/rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` may be able to help; otherwise, you've got some debugging and sleuthing to do.